# My Bootstrap layout contains large gaps that I would like removed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to achieve the layout you see below:

[image]

The  markup that controls this looks as follows:

```
    <div class="droppable col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-2" style="border: 1px solid; border-color: #e6e6e6;">
```

Each of the six columns represents a particular business and underneath each business is a variable number of employees that isn't known until the page is rendered. I'm wondering why there is such a large gap in the middle of the layout. I don't understand why Bootstrap wasn't able to bring BGSU 1, Flower Hospital, Imagination Station and Lords Sophia up, to fill in the gap. The room is certainly there.

Comment: you can try to make each column a parent to the objects it contains `<div><div> at&t </div> <div>BGSU 1 <div> </div>`

Comment: You're looking for [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/). Alternatives: [tiny-masonry](https://github.com/aishikaty/tiny-masonry), [bootstrap-waterfall](https://github.com/Mystist/bootstrap-waterfall) (google for more). A CSS only alternative is to use [CSS columns](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/) - but it could get confusing for users when/if resizing (as elements change columns sharply and are hard to follow - the content flow is similar to newspaper columns - which means you can't have very tall columns ***and*** allow resize).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap by *definition* works `row` *then* `column`. You have six columns per row, and each row is as tall as the tallest column contained within. As such, each of the columns in your second row *start* from the top of the tallest column in your first row (Monroe).

It is **impossible** to shift these columns 'up', at least in the traditional Bootstrap sense.

Having said that, you appear to have three columns all stacked on top of one another in the top-right. You may benefit from splitting these columns out, as this would shrink the height of the tallest column, thus shrinking that whole row. This would be done with something like `col-md-8`, though may make the columns too squished for your liking.

You may also be able to benefit from using some of Bootstrap's [responsive utilies](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/) in conjunction with a clearfix, like `<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>`. This would allow you to 'break' specificly on certain viewports.

However, you would benefit best from switching to something like CSS Grid, and make use of its [automatic placement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Auto-placement_in_CSS_Grid_Layout), which allows you to specify whether each column is large, medium or small, and shift the columns around accordingly, to achieve a stacking effect. Obviously, this would require a fairly hefty restructure, and you may find that it's too much of a trade-off.